# Why does setting a variable equal to another variable change anything in this code?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, godot

I'm having some problems with the following code (Python):

```
x = [0,0]
y = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
z = y
# z = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]

print(y)
for i in range(0,len(z)):
    if i == 0:
        z[i] = x
    else:
        z[i] = y[i-1]
print(y)

y = z

print(y)
for i in range(0,len(z)):
    if i == 0:
        z[i] = x
    else:
        z[i] = y[i-1]
print(y)
```

What I'd expect as the output is

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

but what I get is

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

and when I instead use the line I commented out for z, I get

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Why aren't lines 1&2 and 3&4 of the output always the same? As far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything to change y (other than y=z) and I don't understand why using z=y or z = [...] at the beginning makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `z = y` sets `z` to point to the same object as `y` points to. If you then write `z = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`, `z` no longer points to the same object as `y`, it points to a different object that has the same values.

Comment: Why does that change the second line of my output? I might just not be understanding something simple, but shouldn't `y` be the same between the first and second times I print it regardless of what `z` is?

Comment: `y` and `z` are the same thing with different names. If you change `z`, `y` changes as well

Answer (score 3):

Change this line `z = y` to

```
from copy import deepcopy 

z = deepcopy(y)
```

Your code will work fine.

Comment: I originally had the problem in GDscript and changed to Python to post it here because I thought I'd be more likely to get help that way. I'm more interested in knowing why I'm having the problem in the first place than it just being fixed.

Comment: @user44557 I was editing my answer for more clarification, But the question closed, and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list you can find your answer better. surely the problem is assigning a list to another variable and if you change one, the other will change too.